# Use org-mode radio targets plural

Tags: org-mode

I search for a solution to reference (preferably automatically) radio targets, which are used in plural form in text blocks.

For example, given the radio target `<<<message>>>`, uses of `message` in the text are automatically linked to the radio target. However, the plural form `messages` will not be linked. I tried to use internal links `[[message]]s` with no success (the link can resolved, but why is this so?).

The only workaround I can think of is explicitly addin a link target `<<messages>>`. However, I still have to insert the link manually.
What makes thins worse is, that the link works in org-mode, but after html export the link references to a random footnote.
Exports to odt are better, however the text is replaced by a number. So i would have to insert `[[messages][messages]]`. That looks ugly.

Any suggestions?

I would dream of haveing the ability to note plural version in radio target, e.g. `<<<message|messages>>>` with only message being inserted visually.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same task and tried inserting a `ZERO WIDTH SPACE` and that seems to so what I want.

Between the singular stem and the plural 's' type `Ctrl-x 8 RET` then type `ZERO WIDTH SPACE`.

Comment: I love this hack. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

There are two challenges to address to get what you want.

1. org uses regexp-quote to construct the radio-target regexp for fontification, which means you can't use something like "messages?" as a regexp to match message or messages. I am not sure what the consequences of not quoting these are.
2. When you click on a link that points to a radio target, org builds a regexp to search for <<>> which it won't find if you defined it with a regexp. This is harder to fix.

The exports are a whole different issue.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a creative way to handle plurals. :)

Define:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'org-entities-user
             '("s" "s" nil "s" "s" "s" "s"))
(add-to-list 'org-entities-user
             '("es" "es" nil "es" "es" "es" "es"))
```

Then:

```
<<<message>>>

Some message\s have little content.
```